# How can I make a PHP error page?

Tags: php

How can I make a script that tells me what the error is when there is one in PHP?

I would assume I'd make a 500.shtml document, but what would I put in it?

Comment: `trigger_error("I'm a PHP error page!");`

Comment: And make sure error reporting is on, of course.

Comment: @GordonM will this echo out the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created one recently. Maybe you can use it.

```
<?php

Class ErrorHandler
{
    private function __construct() { }

    public static function SetHandler($errTypes = ERROR_TYPES)
    {
        return set_error_handler(array('ErrorHandler' , 'Handler'), $errTypes);
    }

    public static function Handler($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine)
    {
        $backtrace = ErrorHandler::GetBacktrace(2);
        //Creating error message.
        $error_message = "\nErrNo: $errNo\n TEXT: $errStr\n LOCATION: $errFile\n LINE: $errLine at" . date('F j, Y, g:i:a') . " Showing Backtrace: $backtrace". "\n";

        if(LOG_ERRORS)
            error_log($error_message, 3 , LOG_ERROR_FILE);

        if(SEND_ERROR_MAIL == true)
            error_log($error_message, 1, ADMIN_ERROR_MAIL, "From: ". SENDMAIL_FROM . "\r\nTo: " . ADMIN_ERROR_MAIL);

        if( ($errNo == E_WARNING && IS_WARNING_FATAL ==false) || ($errNo == E_NOTICE || $errNo == E_USER_NOTICE) )
        {
            if(DEBUGGING)
                echo '<div class="error_box"> <b> <pre>' . $error_message. '</pre> </b> </div>';
        } else {
            if(DEBUGGING)
                echo '<div class="error_box"> <b> <pre>' . $error_message. '</pre> </b> </div>';
            else
            {
                echo SITE_GENERIC_FORM_MESSAGE;
                /*ob_clean();
                include '500.php';
                flush();
                ob_flush();
                ob_end_clean();
                exit();*/
            }
            exit();
        }
    }

    public static function GetBacktrace($irrelevantFirstEntries)
    {
        $s = '';
        $MAXSTRLEN = 64;
        $trace_array = debug_backtrace();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $irrelevantFirstEntries; $i++)
            array_shift($trace_array);

        $tabs = sizeof($trace_array) - 1;

        foreach($trace_array as $arr)
        {
            $tabs = $tabs - 1;
            if(isset($arr['class']))
                $s = $s . $arr['class'] . '.';
            $args = array();

            if(!empty($arr['agrs']))

                foreach($arr['args'] as $v)
                {
                    if(is_null($v))
                    $args[] = 'null';
                    elseif (is_array($v))
                        $args[] = 'Array[' . sizeof($v) . ']';
                    elseif (is_object($v))
                        $args[] = 'Object: ' . get_class($v);
                    elseif (is_bool($v))
                        $args[] = $v?'true':'false';
                    else
                    {
                        $v = (string)@$v;
                        $str = htmlspecialchars(substr($v, 0, $MAX STRLEN));
                        if (strlen($v) > $MAXSTRLEN)
                            $str = $str . "...";
                        $args[] = '"'.$str.'"';
                    }
                }

                $s = $s . $arr['function'] . '(' . implode(', ', $args). ')';
                $line = (isset ($arr['line']) ? $arr['line'] : "unknown");
                $file = (isset ($arr['file']) ? $arr['file'] : "unknown");
                $s = $s . sprintf(' # line %4d, file: $s', $line, $file);
                $s = $s . '\n';
        }
        return $s;

    }
}

?>
```

Some changes required, obviously. Just include this file in your index.php.

Comment: thank you. i don't know why everyone else didn't get that..

Answer (score 0):

Some server has default config set not to show PHP errors. You can override it using something like

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I believe the question he is asking is how to make a *custom* error page.

Comment: @EricH No, like he said he wanted "a script that tells me what the error is when there is one in PHP?" so clearly he wanted to know what the error is when PHP throws out an error.

Comment: @DexterHuinda Yep, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You get warnings and errors without asking in php, just set

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll know when an error occurs.